# If I make a mobile app which searches google very frequently itself (sth. like bot) will google tolerate it?

Tags: android, search

If I make a program which searches google itself (sth. like bot) will google tolerate it?

Just wondering what are the conditions when mobile app can make searches using google frequently without being banned? And when this type of program will be banned.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: How can you know it in detail if you haven't programmed this type of logic?